# laravel 5.3 login with facebook

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am implementing login with facebook in my laravel 5.3 project. It seems to work as I get all the data recorded to the database from a facebook user, but my project sees my auth state as not logged. Also it does not redirect me to the dashboard, but displays a white page with the callback link. Why?

It redirects a user to the fagebook page to login

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}
```

Callback Handler

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    try{
        $socialUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }

    $user = User::where('facebook_id', $socialUser->getId())->first();
    if(!$user){
        User::create([
            'facebook_id' => $socialUser->getId(),
            'name' => $socialUser->getName(),
            'email' => $socialUser->getEmail(),
        ]);

        auth()->login($user);
        return redirect()->to('/dashboard');
    }
}
```

My auth()->login seems not to work, and redirect also. What may be the problem? Thank you!

routes:

```
Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'PageController@getDashboard']);

Route::get('auth/facebook', 'Auth\RegisterController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/facebook/callback', 'Auth\RegisterController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Comment: I have an idea what the problem is, can you confirm if the User::create is actually creating the user in the database?

Comment: yes! and my proj redirects to the facebook login, I login, and then I am redirected to my project /auth/facebook/callback/token

Comment: I have put an answer below, your current code doesn't do anything if the user exists @Andrew T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour seems correct for the way you have coded the callback handler. I believe what you want to happen is if the user exists then you want to log them in, your current code doe's nothing if the user exists so you need to make sure if the user exists that they are logged in.

I would change the code as follows:

```
$user = User::where('facebook_id', $socialUser->getId())->first();

if(!$user){
    User::create([
        'facebook_id' => $socialUser->getId(),
        'name' => $socialUser->getName(),
        'email' => $socialUser->getEmail(),
    ]);       
}

if(Auth::loginUsingId($user->id)){
    return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
}
```

This way if there is a user they will still be logged in rather than the handler doing nothing

Comment: didn't think about that :D I'll try it now